# Software corruption

Tags: software-distribution

I have the following questions

(1) What is meant by the term "Software corruption" ? Any concrete example would be a great help.

(2) If there is something called "software corruption" how can this be repaired?

I would be very grateful for the responses.

Comment: Where did you come across the term? A link would be helpful to gain context.

Comment: I was in a meeting where people were discussing about it. I myself have never seen it used .

Comment: And in this meeting, in what context was it used?

Comment: I found references to it here - http://www.buzzle.com/editorials/8-28-2006-106793.asp . Looks like a system administration issue, so I'm recommending the question be moved to serverfault. That would also explain why you are drawing a blank here. Folks there might be able to tell you all about it.

Comment: I did not really understand but one guy told that if magnetic disk inadvertently gets corrupted then it is called software corruption but I am not convinced about this. Is it really software corruption? Actually they wanted to have a maintainence facility to store the several versions of the software so that bugs reported by the user can be easily fixed and right version can be delivered to the user, after the development has ceased. Then someone raised the question about the course of action to be taken in case of  software corruption.

Answer (score 4):

*Software corruption* is an ambiguous term. I can think of two possible meanings:

1. *Corruption in software*: Data corruption of program binaries (by any cause, e.g. hardware fault, software bug, or user error). The damaged software can often be reinstalled to fix the program.
2. *Corruption by software*: Data corruption (of any data) that is caused by buggy software (as opposed to a hardware fault).

Answer (score 0):

Software corruption generally means some part of the software package or its dependencies are unusable because of reasons like virus, deletion, stupid editing of config files, by some bug, etc.

In windows, it is generally some dll stopped working.